# Youtube API get Livestream scheduledStartTime

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I need to obtain the list of upcoming livestream from my Youtube Channel and show them to my website visitors.

Problem is that with the simple API Key http request ('https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/') I can't access to scheduledStartTime value.

The only way to do that is using an oauth authentication, so the request would be
'GET [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts'](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts%27) with a token.

This is the code I'm using with the basic API key request:

```
<?php


$base_url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/';

$key = 'API KEY';

$channelId = 'CHANNEL ID';

$maxResults = 30;

$API_URL_LIVE_UPCOMING = $base_url . 'search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=' .$channelId. '&maxResults=' .$maxResults. '&eventType=upcoming&type=video&key=' .$key;
   
$url_upcoming = $API_URL_LIVE_UPCOMING;

$json = file_put_contents('youtube-cache-upcoming.json', file_get_contents($url_upcoming));
   
$json_data = file_get_contents('youtube-cache-upcoming.json'); 

foreach ( $json_data->items as $item ) {
    $id = $item->id->videoId;
    $title = $item->snippet->title;
    $publishTime = $item->snippet->publishTime;
    $description = $item->snippet->description;
    $thumbnail = $item->snippet->thumbnails;
    $mediumThumbnail = $thumbnail->medium->url;
    
    echo '<div class="16022021" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #647279; margin-bottom:4%;margin-top:4%;padding-bottom: 30px; width: 100%;">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-7">';
    //echo '<p style="font-size:1.2em;">'.$publishTime.'</p>';
    echo '<p style="font-size:1.4em;color:#FF714D"><strong>'.$title.'</strong></p>';
    echo '<p style="font-size:1.2em;">'.$description. '</p>';
    echo '<p style="margin-top:4%;"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$id.'">VIEW VIDEO</a></p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-5 align-left"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id.'?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';        
    //echo '<div class="col-md-5 align-left"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$id.'"><img class="img-responsive" alt="'.$title.'" src="'.$mediumThumbnail.'" title="'.$title.'" /></a></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

I basically would like to obtain a similar simple result, would be great to see a coding example on how to manage the auth process and show the response on an html page, without installing any library.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would expect that that is private user data, you will need to be authenticated as the owner of the channel to see something like that.   Have you tried? using Oauth2 can we see your code?

Comment: I would like to know where to start with Oauth2 code. 
I've my ID client OAuth 2.0 already Configured from https://console.cloud.google.com/

I've already tested the api call on the testing console https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts and it returns the info I need... example scheduledStartTime": "2021-02-16T15:00:00Z",

I just don't undestand how to implement the authentication in the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to obtain the scheduledStartTime value in a different way, without Oauth2.

Basically, I'm using two api calls:
the first one is

> [https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=%27)
> .$channelId. '&maxResults=' .$maxResults.
> '&eventType=upcoming&type=video&key=' .$key;

Then for any video id I call the videos endpoint:

> [https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id='](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id=%27)
> .$id. '&key=' .$key;

Here I can extract the scheduledStartTime value for any videos.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example of the youtube.liveBroadcasts.list method.

```
<?php

/**
 * Sample PHP code for youtube.liveBroadcasts.list
 * See instructions for running these code samples locally:
 * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#php
 */

if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new Exception(sprintf('Please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "%s"', __DIR__));
}
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('API code samples');
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
]);

// TODO: For this request to work, you must replace
//       "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json" with a pointer to your
//       client_secret.json file. For more information, see
//       https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys
$client->setAuthConfig('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

// Request authorization from the user.
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
printf("Open this link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
print('Enter verification code: ');
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for an access token.
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Define service object for making API requests.
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$queryParams = [
    'id' => 'YOUR_BROADCAST_ID'
];

$response = $service->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts('snippet,contentDetails,status', $queryParams);
print_r($response);
```